# Jenkins withCredentials gitUsernamePassword GIT issue

Tags: authentication, jenkins, jenkins-git-plugin

I have an issue with pushing to repo using jenkins git plugin.
I'm using `withCredentials([gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: 'id')])`
I'm have credentials looks like `user@support.com`, so then I'm trying to push I see an error `Authentication failed` .

Probably git plugin couldn't process login which looks like user@support.com, due to this fact auth looks like **https://user@support.com@site_name, 2 symbols "@" in 1 string.**

```
17:18:02  14:18:02.696390 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'push' 'origin' 'branch_name'
17:18:02  14:18:02.697060 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'git-remote-https' 'origin' 'https://site_name/repo_name.git'
17:18:02  14:18:02.824423 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: **** 'Username for '\''https://site_name'\'': '
17:18:02  14:18:02.827488 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: **** 'Password for '\''https://user@support.com@site_name'\'': '
17:18:05  remote: Invalid username or password
17:18:05  fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://site_name/repo_name.git/'
```

Any suggestions?